# Prove that $x+y+z=3$ $\implies$ $x^xy^yz^z\ge1$

Tags: inequality, lagrange-multiplier, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, jensen-inequality

If $x,y,z$ are positive real numbers such that $x+y+z=3$, prove that
$$x^xy^yz^z\ \ge\ 1$$
**My attempt**
This is equivalent to
$$x\ln x + y\ln y + z\ln z\ \ge\ 0$$
By AM-GM

$\dfrac{x\ln x + y\ln y + z\ln z}3 \ge \sqrt[3]{xyz(\ln x)(\ln y)(\ln z)}$

I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use AM–GM: some of the terms on the LHS may be negative. Try Jensen's inequality instead.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** :

$x \longmapsto x\ln(x)$ is convex. Use convexity inequality aka Jensen's inequality to prove your result.

Answer (score 1):

$1+\ln x$ is injective on $x \in (0,\infty)$ so it follows by Lagrange multipliers, that the minimum of $x^xy^yz^z$ subject to $x+y+z=3$ must occur when $x=y=z$:

From Lagrange multipliers we must solve the system,

$$x^x(1+\ln x)y^yz^z=\lambda$$

$$y^y(1+\ln y)x^xz^z=\lambda$$

$$z^z(1+\ln z)x^xy^y=\lambda$$

This means we must have $1+\ln x=1+\ln y=1+\ln z$.

With the bordered hessian technique you can show that $x=y=z=1$ does indeed give a minimum of $x^xy^yz^z=1$.

Comment: What does "invective" mean?

Comment: Spelling...@martycohen

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x\ln{x}$.

Hence, $f''(x)=\frac{1}{x}>0$, which says that $f$ is a convex function.

Thus, by Jensen $$\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}x\ln{x}}{3}\geq\frac{x+y+z}{3}\ln\frac{x+y+z}{3}=0$$ and we are done!